# Batch file to copy directory with files from one location to the current directory the file is in

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that I can place in a folder and have it copy files the directory structure and the files from a networked location. I know this can be achieved using xcopy the issue I am having is it is not placing it in the folder where the batch file was copied. How can this be achieved so that I don't have to rewrite the file for every new folder I want this copied to? Here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off

Title xcopybatch.bat

REM Copy Directory Structure using xcopy Windows native command
REM -------------------------- Enter Source Directory ---------------------------
set "dir1=K:\GIS\Dallas Area 500-100 Year BFE Maps\_Misc Flood Info\"
REM -------------------------- Enter Dest Directory -----------------------------
set "dir2=K:."
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
xcopy "%dir1%" "%dir2%" /e
pause
REM --------------------------------- Exit --------------------------------------
:end
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: What exactly "is not placing it in the folder"?

Comment: I think your question isn't quite worded correctly.  I think what you are trying to accomplish is you want the files copied to the directory that the batch file is executing from.  If that is the cast then use `%~dp0`.That represents the script directory.

Comment: that is correct I am trying to get it to copy the folder and files to the folder that the batch file is executed from

Comment: Is there a way that I can make it so this file can be run once and then will remove itself?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want to dump this script into a folder then run it, it will copy files from your source location, then self destruct (delete itself)?

By the way, if you're clarifying the parameters of a question, you should edit the question to reflect that.

with Xcopy, ommiting the target directory will assume you want the current working directory, but if you want to be sure, just implicitly specify `%~dp0` as the target

```
xcopy "%dir1%" "%~dp0" /e
```

To have it delete itself, add this line at the very end

```
DEL "%~f0"
```

Just as `%~dp0` give you the batch file's directory, `%~f0` is the file name of the batch file.  Because the CLI parses the entire file, it will run from memory, then delete itself.